# 'student at the university' and article 'a'

Tags: vocabulary, articles

I think it's okay to say "I study [subject] at the  University of [City] ". However,  should I say

> I'm a physics student at ...

or without 'a',

> I'm physics student at ...

I'm suddenly terribly unsure which one is correct, so maybe you lot can help.

Comment: Take out the word 'physics'. Would you say "I am [a] student at ..."? You might find more help on our sister site [ell.se].

Comment: This question appears would be better asked on ELL.

Comment: Predicate nouns that are count nouns (like _student_, but not like _rice_) require an indefinite article (_a/an_). Thus, _I am **a** student_, but _This is rice_.

Answer (score 3):

> "I'm suddenly terribly unsure which one is correct, so maybe you lot can help.".

It all depends on the noun you use.

**First, let's look at your first example:**

> "I study [subject] at the University of [City]".

or

> "I study physics at the University of Miami."

In this sentence, **"physics"** is an [uncountable noun](http://www.really-learn-english.com/uncountable-nouns.html) (or noncount noun). That means it cannot be counted.

We cannot say, "1 physics, 2 physics, 3 physics."

Uncountable nouns do not require an [indefinite article](http://www.really-learn-english.com/english-grammar-articles.html).

For example:

- Please buy **sugar**. (Incorrect: Please buy a sugar.)
- Love is **blind**. (Incorrect: A love is blind.)
- I like **coffee**. (Incorrect: I like a coffee.)

See more examples of uncountable nouns here: [Uncountable Nouns](http://www.really-learn-english.com/uncountable-nouns.html)

**Now, your second example:**

> "I'm a physics student at the University of Miami."

In this case, **"physics"** is not a noun. It is actually an adjective that tells us what kind of student.

So, we look to the noun **"student"**. "Student" is a [countable noun](http://www.really-learn-english.com/countable-nouns.html) (or count noun). That means it can be counted. We can say, "1 student, 2 students, 3 students."

Countable nouns do require an article (such as an indefinite article "a" or "an" or the definite article "the"), a quantitity word (some, three, many), or a possessive adjective (my, our, their).

For example:

- I saw **a mouse**. (indefinite article)
- Did you see **the show**? (definite article)
- He needs **three books**. (quantity word)
- That is **my house**. (possessive adjective)
- That is **my red house**. (This one has an adjective before the noun, like your example)

Read more about countable nouns here: [Countable Nouns](http://www.really-learn-english.com/countable-nouns.html)

Comment: But you can say "I am student" without article. There's more to the story than countable/uncountable.

Comment: No, I would never say, "I am student." I might say, "I am A student." But, I can't think of any instance when someone would say, "I am student." If there is more to this question than countable/uncountable noun, then please explain in context. I would be happy to look at other explanations.

Comment: [Google N-grams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+student%2CI+am+a+student&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) supports what you say. Maybe I was under false impression all the time.